# Probability involving set

Tags: probability-theory

$A$ is a set containing $ n$ elements.a subset $P$ of $A$ is chosen at random and  the set $A$ is  reconstructed by replacing the elements of $P$.a subset $Q $ of $ A$ is again chosen at random.then the probability that

**The number of elements in P equals the number of elements in Q.**

For any arbitrary element $a € A$ there are the following different possibilities

$a$  €  $P$  and $a$ € $ Q$

$a$ € $P$ and doesn't belong to $Q$

$ a$ € $Q$ and doesn't belong to$ P$

$ a $ doesn't belong to$ P $ and $Q$

So these are possible ways

Every element of $P$ is in $Q$

Some element of$ P$ is in $Q $and some not while equal number of elements of $Q$ is not in $P$

The two sets $P $and $Q$ don't have any common element between them.

However I couldn't put in form of some equation.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "a subset of $A$ is chosen at random" do you mean that each subset of $A$ is equally likely to be chosen? Or some other distribution, like "each element of $A$ has probability $p$ of being in $P$" ?

Comment: @Ned all subsets of $A$ are equally likely.